# Android registerForActivityResult callback not called when Activity launched from another registerForActivityResult callback

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, registerforactivityresult

I have these `Activities`, each one has its own navigation tree and a default (main) `Fragment`:

```
class MainActivity: Activity

class ActivityA: Activity

class ActivityB: Activity
```

In the fragment in `MainActivity` I have several activity launchers. When I call these launchers from an `onClickListener` (for example), things work as expected, I navigate to the destination `Activity`, I do what I have to do there, I finish the activity from its fragment:

```
activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)
activity.finish()
```

And finally I get the callback in the activity launcher from where the activity was launched.

But, when I launch an activity from another launcher, the callback will not be triggered.
Here it is a simple code to explain the problem:

The `MainFragment` of the `MainActivity`:

```
class MainFragment: Fragment {
  val activityALauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
    launchActivityB() // The callback in activityBLauncher will NOT be triggered after ActivityB is finished
  }

  val activityBLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
  }

  fun launchActivityA() {
    val intent = Intent(activity, A::class.java)
    activityALauncher.launch(intent)
  }

  fun launchActivityB() {
    val intent = Intent(activity, B::class.java)
    activityBLauncher.launch(intent)
  }

  // For example is called in onClickListener
  fun someRandomFun() {
    launchActivityB() // The callback in activityBLauncher will be triggered after ActivityB is finished
  }
}
```

This is how `ActivityA` is finished from `MainFragmentA`:

```
class MainFragmentA: Fragment {

  ...
  activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)
  activity.finish()
  ...
  
}
```

This is how `ActivityB` is finished from `MainFragmentB`:

```
class MainFragmentB: Fragment {

  ...
  activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)
  activity.finish()
  ...
  
}
```

Any solution to this?

**EDIT**

For each `registerForActivityResult` we will get a callback in `onActivityResult` at the host activity `MainActivity`.
Usually, after `onActivityResult` in host activity, then the callback in `registerForActivityResult` will be triggered, this seems to be by design.
But in this particular case I never get the callback in `registerForActivityResult` but I still get in `onActivityResult`

Comment: Have you tried placing the "super()" call inside "onActivityResult()" of the activity to top instead of placing it at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me add this in your gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-alpha04'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-alpha04'
```

Comment: I'm using `1.4.1` the latest till this date, but same problem.

Comment: is your activity is being launched as a singleInstance or singleTask?

Comment: `MainActivity` is `singleTask`. `ActivityA` and `ActivityB` are `standard`

Comment: i think this can help you https://www.quinbay.com/blog/activityresultcontract-activityresultapis-in-androidx